# How to align googleads library with Google Ads API v2 deprecation?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-ads-api

I have a daily Python script that pulls data from the Google Ads API. I had the v20.0.0 of the google ads library installed. On October 28, it started failing with this error:

```
Error with message " Version v2 is deprecated. Requests to this version will be blocked."
```

I assume this is because of this setup line:

```
ga_service = client.get_service('GoogleAdsService', version='v2')
```

But when I change that to `v3` (just a guess, since the error message doesn't tell me what versions are accepted), I get this when I run the script:

```
ValueError: Specified Google Ads API version "v3" does not exist. Valid API versions are: "v2", "v1"
```

I ran `pip install --upgrade googleads`, which got me up to `v25.0.0`, but still got the same errors. I then uninstalled and re-installed `googleads`, but still get the same errors.

I haven't been able to find a migration guide in Google's documentation. Does anyone know how to update the package and script to get it running again?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api

Comment: [Google ads python library](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/#getting-started)

Comment: I'm a bit confused because `GoogleAdsService` is only available in the Google Ads API, but the package you mention, `googleads` is for interacting with the Google Adwords API.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the old Api you are using google says it still works but, by the looks of it they have integrated the [new api](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/) into it. I am assuming this because they ended support of v2 of the new api on October 21, 2020 which coincides with your error.

I would look at upgrading to the [new api](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/) over trying to update what v2 code they have used as v3 is also ending soon and v6 has just been released. I have had some errors from v4 to v5 so it will be easier to just do the upgrade.

Good luck as its not just an update they have changed a fair amount from the older version.